# How to fetch number of occurences of a property in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, rdfs

The aim is to fetch the **number of occurences** of all properties of domain
**dbo:Place**. Similar to stats available here- http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/statistics/stats-properties-stats.json Snippet given below:

[image: Occurences of Properties]

So until now I have fetched all the properties and I am stuck on
finding its number of occurence. I believe there are 3 ways but I'm confused as to which one is the correct method.

1. Method 1- Using dbo

   ```
   SELECT (count(distinct ?s) as ?count) 
   WHERE {
     ?s dbo:employer ?o .
   }
   ```

OUTPUT: 8744

2. Method 2- Using dbp

   ```
   SELECT (count(distinct ?s) as ?count) 
   WHERE {
     ?s dbp:employer ?o .
   }
   ```

   OUTPUT: 11082
3. Method 3- Using UNION of dbo and dbp

   ```
   SELECT (count(distinct ?s) as ?count) 
   WHERE {
     { ?s dbo:employer ?o . }
   UNION
     { ?s dbp:employer ?o . }
   }
   ```

   OUTPUT: 11176

Also, I haven't mentioned dbo:Place in any of the queries so is it correct?

Comment: there is no proper answer to this, `dbo:employer` and `dbp:employer` are technically different properties from different extraction methods. Clearly, the stats in your screenshot are just based on the mapping-based properties aka `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` namespace -those proeprties are typed, i.e. you get object and data properties.

Comment: if you want to restrict the stats to just instances of `dbo:Place` you have to add another triple pattern `?s a dbo:Place .`

Comment: what is the purpose of those stats?

Comment: Thanks fro the quick response @UninformedUser . I am using those stats to filter properties that have count less than a certain threshold so that I don't query all the properties for purpose.

Comment: Also if I add this query: ```SELECT (count(distinct ?s) as ?count) 
WHERE {
  ?s dbo:employer ?o .
  ?s a dbo:Place .
} ``` the count is 1. But the actual value is very big.

Comment: Ah! Initially, I thought that ```dbo:employer``` is linked with ```dbo:Place``` substantially but that's not the case hence the low count. But when I tried the same query with ```dbo:anthem``` or ```dbp:anthem``` I get many values.